# Distribution of $Z=mX$ if $X$ has a stable distribution and $m \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

[Stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) distributions can be uniquely characterized by three parameters $\alpha, c$ and $\mu$. Its characteristic function is then given by
$$\phi_X(t)=\exp (i t \mu - |ct|^{\alpha})$$

What happens if we multiply $X$ by a constant $m$? More concretely, what would be $\phi_Z(t)$ if $Z=mX$? I suspect that since $c$ is the "scale" parameter, maybe we should multiply it by $m$, and do the same to $\mu$ since it is the mean of the distribution. Can someone help me check these claims?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you express the characteristic function of $Z$ in terms of $\Phi_X$?

Comment: The function you mention is the cumulative distribution function right? @Michh If yes I have done that.

Comment: $\phi_{mX}(t)=E[e^{it(mX)}]=E[e^{i(tm)X}]=\phi_X(mt)$

Comment: Thank you @Henry. You can post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requested from comments:

$$\phi_{mX}(t)=E[e^{it(mX)}]=E[e^{i(tm)X}]=\phi_X(mt)$$